# How does jQuery-UI know how to bind event callbacks supplied as init options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, callback, initialization

How does jQuery-UI know to bind callbacks passed as init options? I'm thinking the answer is somewhere in the [$.widget.bridge method (ln 71)](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L71) but I'm not entirely sure what's going on there.

An example of what I'm talking about is something like the [autocomplete search event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#events). The code example shows that I can bind to 'search' with init options but I don't see anything specific to this behavior autocomplete's code.

This technique seems cool. I'd like to leverage it.

Comment: Are you wondering specifically about jQueryUI, or just generally about how a plugin calls a callback passed as an option?

Comment: curious about how jqueryUI does it specifically. If the technique has a more general name that'd be interesting to know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with the jQueryUI code, but here's an example of how you could call a callback passed as an argument.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/pshLK/

When the example loads, you'll get 2 alerts. This is the result of the callback that was passed running for both of the matched `<div>` elements. You can change the callback function and click "Run" at the top to see that your callback is running.

```
(function($) {
       // create myPlugin
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
           // iterate through all elements the selector matched
        return this.each(function() {
                // Change the color to blue
            $(this).css('color','blue');
                // Call the callback using the .call() method
                //    so that we can pass the value of "this"
                //    as the element in the iteration
            options.callback.call(this);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

   // Find all <div> elements on the page, and call myPlugin which
   //   receives an object as an argument that has a "callback" property
   //   whose value is the function that will be called in the plugin.
$('div').myPlugin({
         // This function will run for each <div> displaying the ID of the <div>
    callback:function() { alert('the id is ' + this.id); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions in JavaScript can be passed as values to other functions and executed. E.g.:

```
function execute(fn)
{
    fn(); // execute function passed as a parameter
}

var alertHelloWorld = function ()
{
    alert("Hello World");
};

execute(alertHelloWorld); // this will alert "Hello World"
```

So what the jQuery Autocomplete plug-in is doing, is caching whatever functions are passed in it's initializer, and then executing them when it needs to. I.E.: when data needs to be handled or when data has been handled.

Here's an example, somewhat similar to the Autocomplete plug-in:

```
// execute three functions contained in an object literal
function execute(o)
{
    o.One();
    o.Two();
    o.Three();
};

// call "execute" passing in object literal containing three anonymous functions
// this will alert "One", then "Two", then "Three"
execute(
{
    One: function () { alert("One"); },
    Two: function () { alert("Two"); },
    Three: function () { alert("Three"); }
});
```

Parameters can also be passed from a function that is executing another function:

```
function execute(fn)
{
    // execute function passed as a parameter with a parameter
    fn("Hello World");
};

execute(function (s)
{
    // parameter "s" supplied by "execute" will contain "Hello World"
    alert(s);
});
```